# R text mining package updating the corpus by modifying or deleting existing documents

Tags: r, text, text-mining

I would like to modify an existing document indexed by a corpus by  doing something simple like this

```
myCorpus[[10]] = "hey I am the new content of this document"
```

Is this valid?

Comment: I guess you want append your corpus List of textDocument ?

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what do you want to do with your corpus. append your Corpus or modify the 10th element?

I want to say that as a syntax it is correct but as semantic is false.

Conceptually a corpus is a metadata and a list of TextDocument. So,
You can access this list as any R list with '[[' or with '$'.

So if you do ( It is better to use <- than = even is here they are equivalent)

```
myCorpus[[10]] <- "hey I am the new content of this document"
```

This will create or change the 10th element , but with an element of class **character** not a **TextDocument**. So you can't apply use methods on class

So To update the content of 10 text document:

```
Content(myCorpus[[10]]) <- "hey I am the new content of this document"
```

To create new elements use :

```
tmUpdate(ovid, DirSource(txt))
```

The source is checked for new files which do not already exist in the document collection. 
are parsed and added to the existing document collection.

Comment: Thanks agustdy for your help. That was very resourceful. How is tmcombine different than tmupdate? the manual for R's tm package talks about tmcombine by means of column concatenation.

Comment: tm_combine? it is used by the R generic function `c` , c(corpus1, corpus2) like c(1,1) see ?c for more information.